# Use the standard "overwrite" dialog with custom information

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, standard-library

I am writing a utility copying files to/from remote drives (eg SkyDrive). When I'm about to overwrite a file, I pop up a regular "file exists, do you want to overwrite Y/N" message box; is it possible to use the standard Windows file overwrite dialog instead? With the three options (copy and replace, don't copy, copy but keep both) and the more detailed size / date information? Or should I just write my own form to duplicate that? (To be honest, I've been searching for this for two days, it would probably have been much faster to just write my own.)

To clarify: I need to show up that dialog *when I choose to* - sometimes I don't want to show it and just want to overwrite the file.

If at all possible, I would prefer for this to work in C# / .NET; however, if only an unmanaged solution exists I'll take that too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible! I did this for [Send to Dropbox](https://github.com/varunkho/SendTodropbox) a little add-on utility I wrote for Explorer to right click and send files to a dropbox folder.

Copy [SHFileOperation.cs](https://github.com/varunkho/SendTodropbox/blob/master/source/SDBWorker/SHFileOperation.cs) into your project, and you can invoke it like so:

```
ShellFileOperation.CopyItems(source, target);
```

`source` can have multiple files/directories. Each item must be enclosed in quotes (").

`target` is the destination directory.

Example:

```
ShellFileOperation.CopyItems("\"c:\\foo.txt\" \"c:\\bar.txt\"", "d:\\xyz");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - I already have the copying part taken care of (and I can't easily replace it). I just need to display that overwrite dialog with my own information filled in (NOT automatically read from FileInfo objects or anything).

Comment: This is great, thanks for this! Worked perfectly well with no issues!